# How to disable background interaction when SwiftUI `Menu` is presented

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios17

One subview that I have on one of my screens has a `Menu`, for example:

```swift
ScrollView {
    SubView1()
    SubView2()
    SubView3()
}
```

Then, in `SubView1`:

```swift
private var menuButton: some View {
  Menu {
    VStack {
      Button(role: .destructive) {
        delete()
      } label: {
        Label("Skip Workout", systemImage: "x.circle")
      }
    }
  } label: {
    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
  }
}
```

The problem is that when the menu button is being presented, background interaction is still enabled. That means that if `SubView2` has a button that presents a sheet, if I tap on that button when the Menu is presented, the sheet does not present (in fact it breaks, since the `isPresented` variable is toggled to true but the sheet doesn't present).

One thing we could do is have an overlay in the parent-most view and conditionally show it based on some state variable, which we pass as a binding/environment variable to all the subviews. However, in my opinion this is really clunky; I do not think we should have shared state across all these views just to disable background interaction. A binding is especially clunky if the menu is actually two or more subviews deep. This or an environment-based approach is especially clunky if we have multiple view hierarchies where this behavior is needed; we do not want to have to write a conditional overlay every time.

Any ideas on how to cleanly disable background interaction?

I'm getting this on *real devices* iOS 17.

Comment: I tried recreating your problem but the sheet **was** being presented. Can you show how to reproduce your issue? My `@State var showSheet` variable was inside `SubView2` and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I forgot to add that this only happens on real devices.

Comment: I have a solution but it allows for the sheet to show up as expected on a real device (while dismissing the menu). Is that okay or do you specifically want to disable touch for other views? It's definitely the most viable solution as it doesn't change the structure of your code at all.

Comment: Dismissing the menu is perfectly fine. I just don’t want it to break other modals like it does now, so if you have a solution that dismisses the menu it’s perfect

Comment: Okay perfect I’ll post it within an hour. Don’t have my laptop right now

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is unfortunately a bug in SwiftUI. On the bright side, the workaround is actually quite simple. Just wrap the code which presents the sheet with:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    showSheet = true
}
```

This allows for the Menu to be dismissed and the sheet to show up which is what users would expect anyway. This is a reusable solution (workaround) which doesn't introduce any dependencies / relationships between views.

This is the code that worked on my iPhone 14 with iOS 17.0.3 (real device). The only thing that is required is the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` part. Rest of it was just for testing

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            View1()
            View2()
                .padding(.top, 100)
        }
    }
}
struct View1: View {
    private var menuButton: some View {
      Menu {
        VStack {
          Button(role: .destructive) {
//            delete()
          } label: {
            Label("Skip Workout", systemImage: "x.circle")
          }
        }
      } label: {
          Text("Show Menu")
      }
    }
    var body: some View {
        menuButton
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present Sheet") {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {  // << only thing needed
                showSheet = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Text("Sheet")
        }
    }
}
```

You could maybe get away with making the delay even shorter but `0.1` works consistently for me.

Let me know if this works on your device(s). Best of luck!

Comment: This works, I think the only nuisance is that we have to do this for every modal that could present when the menu is open. Hypothetically this could a lot, and ideally we wouldn’t have to do this. 

But it’s an acceptable workaround.